# I have a big table in R, now I want to select the odd rows and paste a label before the first element of this row

Tags: r, loops, select, rows

```
A=matrix(0,4,2)

A[1,1]=2
A[1,2]=3
A[2,1]=2
A[2,2]=3
A[3,1]=2
A[3,2]=3
A[4,1]=2
A[4,2]=3
```

Now I want to pick up row 2,4 and return `this is odd` before the first element of the row.

But I don't know how to make a loop to pick up row 2,4

Comment: You are selecting elements, not rows. Can you revise your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display some text and the first element of all odd rows. You can try this:

```
cat(paste("This is odd", A[c(2,4),1], "\n"))
```

No need for a loop there. Should you want to work with a larger matrix, and take all odd rows, you can use `seq(2, nrow(A), by=2)` instead of `c(2,4)`.

Comment: An easier way to get all even rows would be `A[c(F,T),]`.  To get odd rows, just switch the order of false and true.  No need to use a loop or `seq`, as [R recycles](https://www.inkling.com/read/r-cookbook-paul-teetor-1st/chapter-5/recipe-5-3) values for you.

Comment: @dnlbrky (+1) Yes, that's a nice use of recycling.