# Change half hourly data into hourly in R by removing every other row

Tags: r

I am stuck on a very simple problem. I have a dataset and the data interval is half hourly. I want to change the data into hourly. It can be done easily by removing every other rows or rows which has time ending on 00:30. Any help is highly appreciated.

The sample dataset is as follows:

```
structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), min = c(0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 
30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 
30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 
30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L), hour = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), mon = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), year = c(109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L), wday = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L), yday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009), Discharge = c(36900, 37100, 37100, 37700, 
37800, 37100, 36800, 36100, 36800, 36000, 36600, 36000, 36300, 
36100, 35800, 34500, 34800, 34400, 34200, 34100, 33800, 34800, 
35100, 34900, 34800, 35000, 34600, 34500, 34200, 34300, 34100, 
33700, 33400, 33100, 32400, 32900, 31600, 32200, 32200, 32700, 
32000, 32700, 32100, 32000, 32000, 31900, 32600, 32600, 31800, 
31900)), .Names = c("date", "year", "Discharge"), row.names = 2:51, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R I have a big table in R, now I want to select the odd rows and paste a label before the first element of this row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183394/r-i-have-a-big-table-in-r-now-i-want-to-select-the-odd-rows-and-paste-a-label-b)

Comment: All three answers use boolean subsetting. Is that more efficient or something? I would have done `x[seq(1,nrow(x),2),]`.

Comment: I sometimes give "select the odd elements of a vector" as a homework assignment, so I have (somewhere) a big collection of possible answers.  I just gave the first answer I thought of. (@GSee's answer is better because it both more specific to this problem and more generalizable to other similar tasks.)

Comment: I would suggest *not* closing this question, as the answers are substantially better and the question more clear than the older question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your "date" column is `POSIXlt` you can subset like this to only include the rows that have 0 for the minutes:

```
x[x$date$min == 0,]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfect. This will be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

`R` will "recycle" elements of a vector when they're not long enough.  So to get every other row, you just need this:

```
yourdata[c(TRUE,FALSE),]
```

Comment: I like using this method as well, but I just realized that @GSee's method will work even in the event that the data is dirty and missing a row

Comment: Very true.  I would prefer @GSee's method as well for that very reason, unless I was certain that every other row was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dataf <- dataf[seq(nrow(dataf)) %% 2 == 1,]
```

(or `==0` -- I haven't checked to see if you need odd or even rows)